# What will happen to Stack Overflow now that it has been sold to Prosus for $1.8 Billion?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

What will happen to Stack Overflow now that it has been sold to Prosus for $1.8 Billion?

Source:

- [Software Developer Community Stack Overflow Sold to Tech Giant Prosus for $1.8 Billion](https://www.wsj.com/articles/software-developer-community-stack-overflow-sold-to-tech-giant-prosus-for-1-8-billion-11622648400)
- [Prosus’s Acquisition of Stack Overflow: Our Exciting Next Chapter](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/)

Comment: So the suspicions were true!

Comment: Congrats to everyone at Stack. This is a huge accomplishment.

Comment: Given Prosus is Dutch, I expect the confetti will be replaced with Windmills and Tulips

Comment: @JoeFriend Long time no see. Glad to see you still keep an eye on us. Hope you're doing well.

Comment: @10Rep at Prosus they are surprised they bought a Cooking site as well ....

Comment: @rene Pretty sure they bought it **because** of the cooking site. The geek nest is just a weird bonus.

Comment: The company that owns the SE Network has been called Stack Overflow for some time now, I think. Interpreting this as buying just one site of the network would be really strange, I think.

Comment: Blog post from the CEO: [Prosus’s Acquisition of Stack Overflow: Our Exciting Next Chapter](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosuss-acquires-stack-overflow/)

Comment: @rene *I expect the confetti will be replaced with Windmills and Tulips* - I hope not - the [confetti](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/05/31/shipping-confetti-to-stack-overflows-design-system/) looks confusing enough...

Comment: "Prosus NV said it struck a $1.8 billion deal to acquire Stack Overflow, an online community for software developers, in a bet on growing demand for online tech ***learning***."

I'm already afraid, do they know what they buy ?

Comment: @Larnu https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/

Comment: Oh, this one's gonna need some official explanations.  There's a lot that we could guess about or gesture vividly about, but the core tenet (and a lot of the motivation behind some decisions) has largely been about the investors, the profitability of the platform, and what the actual direction held.  With there now being *an* owner, the existing knowledge or assumptions about what Stack Overflow Inc. is or was is rendered completely invalid.  Only executives or the board could answer this.

Comment: Just to have a link to it, this is posted on MSE as well https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/365050

Comment: In the mean time, some anxiety-laced regret and concern is already starting to course through my psyche, as if I had a chance to read the writing on the wall and chose to ignore it...

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/365052/798831 for some more info.

Comment: @yivi Scroll down to the very bottom of this or any SE network page: "© 2021 Stack Exchange Inc". The company *is* called Stack Exchange Inc.

Comment: @rene Did you know that windmills like music? They tend to be big metal fans.

Comment: @Stargateur Why is it not a place to learn? In microscopic ways? It's not a teaching platform, no - and I don't think that's something anyone would say... but to imply that people aren't *learning* on SO or the rest of the network seems a bit odd. When I ask questions, I learn a ton. When I search and find an answer already on site, I learn. This may be just in time learning instead of lesson plans but it's still *learning*.

Comment: @Catija first, I believe there is a different between "learning" and "learn" you changed the word thus change a lot the thing I was talking about, secondly, sure we can learn from SO, but this trigger some red flag, specially, a Q&A form is not suitable for get starting in something, it's suitable to get answer to specific question and a lot of misinformation lead to a lot of people believing SO is here to help you learn basic of language/programming. This lead to a lot of negative experience. Also, here I speak of stackoverflow itself, not stackexchange other site that I never used.

Comment: @Stargateur I think your concern is a fair one; SO isn't designed to teach people how to code. For people who mistake SO for that, it's a lose-lose for both the individual and the community. However, I still don't think it's wrong to say that SO is an "online teach learning" platform, and I don't think that language is cause for alarm. Every single person on SO (and other network sites) is definitely learning– The core goal of every Stack is to "build a repository of knowledge." That goal is inseparable from using that knowledge for "*learning*", it's just less synchronous than normal teaching

Comment: $1.8 **billion**?  So do those of us who contribute get any of that?

Comment: @Stargateur I think people confuse learning with getting. Most people come to Stack Overflow to have people write code for them. When they don't get any code, they say Stack Overflow is not for learning. But I disagree - if you ask a good question that's productive, then you get an answer. That's the definition of learning. So I solely believe that Stack Overflow is for learning. I learnt a lot of programming from here. And I'm stupid.

Comment: @SteveSummit We're volunteers, aren't we?

Comment: @SteveSummit I was shocked to discover that that number is only a little (~8%) greater than the [total reputation held across Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1417212/sum-of-all-user-reputation-on-site). If it's doled out that way, then you've got a nice gift coming your way!

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira the front end is open source: https://github.com/StackExchange

Comment: [The controlling company has a "glorious" past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naspers): *"...Naspers refused to comply, which led to 127 Naspers employees each making an individual submission to the TRC, apologising for their role in the apartheid years. They said Naspers newspapers had formed an integral part of the power structure which implemented and maintained apartheid through, for instance, supporting the NP in elections and referendums. In 2015, Media24 CEO Esmare Weideman apologised for Naspers's role in supporting apartheid."*. *[Prosus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosus)*

Comment: @SteveSummit "$1.8 billion? So do those of us who contribute get any of that?" It's the other way around unfortunately. By paying $1.8 billion they got us, the content creators. We are now working for them (and for free as always).

Comment: @PM2Ring "Will there be poffertjes? Salmiak? A "coffee" shop? ;)" Prosus is just a daughter of [Naspers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naspers), which is a South African company. So I guess it will rather be curry and chakalaka and wine (I'm looking forward to the wine though).

Comment: The good news is that the new parent company is big. So there is financial stability involved. The bad news is that they may have bought something different from what SO really is, judging by the announcement. Also $1.8 billion really sounds like a lot. Is it really worth that much? If so, we should simply all move away, found our own StackOverflow and sell it for the same price.

Comment: @Trilarion I doubt they'd spend $1.8G on a company that they haven't thoroughly researched.

Comment: @Trilarion Stack Overflow is at the heart of everything related to development and as we can see from the amount of unwanted questions that roll in in some way or another every novice developer learns about Stack Overflow's existence and wants to post questions there rather than somewhere more novice-friendly... that kind of name recognition is worth a lot more than the site software and content itself I would reckon.

Comment: @PM2Ring They have surely thoroughly researched, but still they may have ended up with a conclusion that will prove somewhat wrong in the future. Even thorough research cannot predict the future completely. Maybe they don't have the first hand experience that we have or maybe they see something I cannot yet imagine. We'll see.

Comment: @Stargateur SO is already receiving _massive_ traffic of the kind "I'm too lazy to study beginner learning material, just tell me the answer so I don't have to spend 5 minutes checking a book or using Google". We are talking of thousands of questions like that every day. The company loves massive traffic so they will encourage the behavior rather than seeking to prevent it. Also the soulless "rep hunters" love answering the same question over and over, so they get answered. It's been a very long time since this was a site for professional & enthusiast programmers.

Comment: @Catija SO is for learning but with a very important condition, you already must know a bit. It's definitely not for learning to program from the scratch. Or at the very least, it's very inefficient for that and doesn't scale well. If only beginners would know that there are better ways to learn. On the other hand, once you know a bit, it's really good, one of the best sources of knowledge, practically similar to thousands of programming books in a very special format. Reading on SO is more important than asking for learning. Ask less, read more should be the motto.

Comment: This question really should be featured.

Comment: @10Rep does this really happened ? my comment was deleted ? If yes that's a very bad sign.

Comment: @Trilarion Why should this question be featured? It's an ultimately stupid and pointless one **because nobody except Prosus can answer that** and obviously they aren't going to. So actually, this question should be deleted.

Comment: @IanKemp Well that's humans for you. Just look at the score. Many people seem to think that this is a major event in the history of StackOverflow. They want to discuss it, whether they can get accurate answers or not. I find it very interesting. But I also agree that it's a bit early to tell. Still I think that every user of SO should know of it, therefore the request to feature it.

Comment: I suspect one impact is that SO will become a little less US-centric. The team running SO have no idea how much their attitudes betray a US mindset. The user base is totally international, the company itself isn't.

Comment: @MichaelKay, fingers crossed!

Comment: I take this `not much this year` to mean site advertising (amount and type) will remain the same?

Comment: @MichaelKay Sorry, you'll still have to bear the Strunk & White badge.

Comment: Perhaps this is the cue we've needed to splinter off and have a self-funded self-governed Stack Overflow.  The content essentially already belongs to everyone by way of Creative Commons.  The company doesn't seem to be adding value for the community that couldn't be done via a non-profit entity and board to manage it.  The community here is too important to be left up to the whims of folks with different goals than that of the community itself.  Of course, splintering has serious implications for the health of the community as well.  Hmmmm....

Comment: @Brad I also thought about that. A non-profit organization of the public Q&A knowledge library part might deliver more value in the long run. The good thing is the content license. In principle you could work in parallel, i.e. cross post content on two different platforms for an intermediate time. It's "just" the software and the servers that need to be replaced really. That might limit a potential splintering of the community.

Comment: @Trilarion "A non-profit organization of the public Q&A knowledge library part might deliver more value in the long run" Agreed.  Would be nice if there was a full fork of SO with all the content, rather than starting over from scratch (e.g.: Codidact).  It could have its own original questions and answers, plus a script that would automatically merge new ones (and their changes) from SO periodically.

Comment: Well, at least the Dutch brew good ale:)

Comment: As a consequence, a moderator on *[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)* has stepped down: *[Stack Exchange, Prosus, Naspers, apartheid, and white supremacy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13609)*

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think you're conflating an answer *by* a moderator with the OP *of that thread* stepping away. Another mod [makes reference](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13609/stack-exchange-prosus-naspers-apartheid-and-white-supremacy#comment51664_13609) to them simply being a "*high-rep, high-activity user*".

Comment: @SteveSummit Surprise coincidence: running a `SELECT SUM(Reputation) FROM Users` query on the SEDE gives a result to very close to this 1.8billion. On this reason, we can estimate that 1 rep ≈ 1$. However, fact is that we all knew it even without numbers, and we were here on our own. Furthermore, we have also learnt a lot here.

Comment: @SteveSummit I think we can not say that the company had done anything unlawful or unfair. It is their gun and their foot. (Check my deleted post below.) We can say that we think, the company is doing unimaginably bad *for itself*, but it is its own right to do. Of course our pain is that we worked a lot, partially for the tuning of our Job SO profile and now it all goes into the soup.

Comment: @PeterMortensen He was not a mod, only a power user (note, being power user in physics is a "little" bit more hard than in the IT world).

Comment: See here:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/

Answer (score 81):

Here's my general take (disclaimer: [I am not an employee](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement), nor am I a TV actor)

**Stack Overflow wants to grow**

Nobody has made that a secret. Somehow, you have to make money to keep the lights on. When the new CEO took over [he said](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/21/scripting-the-future-of-stack-2020-plans-vision/)

> It is critically important that we evolve our platform, community infrastructure, and culture to be more useful to our community so we continue to be a core part of a developer’s workflow.

Those things take money. And you don't hire a new CEO to keep the status quo. The best way to do that is to offer stock. The problem is that tech stocks are no longer a sure bet, especially for a company that doesn't seem to have a white-hot product like [Slack](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-55154326) (sold for $27.7B USD). I really don't know that a Stack Overflow IPO would work well enough, and the risk is the stock tanks and takes the company down too.

In this context, selling is the next best option.

**Get a bigger vision**

So what does [Prosus want with SO?](https://www.prosus.com/news/prosus-to-acquire-stack-overflow-for-us18-billion/) (emphasis mine)

> With expertise in scaling communities in high-growth markets globally, Prosus can help accelerate Stack Overflow’s growth ambitions, with a particular focus on reaching a wider international community, while also further scaling the company’s Teams product to position Stack Overflow at the center of product and technology development within major enterprises globally.

> Prosus has built a significant presence on the enterprise side with a focus on the future of workplace learning. **Prosus will reach 90% of the Fortune 100 across its corporate learning companies including Stack Overflow, Skillsoft, Udemy and Codecademy.**

You've probably heard of some of those companies. I know directly that Codecademy has a free tier. How SO fits into that wheelhouse isn't entirely clear, but it's clear there's a theme there. And that theme seems to involve keeping the SO Q&A format as-is in some fashion. That seems to be the recurring message

**[Jeff Atwood](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1400132013068218370?s=19)**

> An exciting day! @spolsky called me and let me know. Today's sale of Stack Overflow, most importantly, lets Stack Overflow continue as an independent site -- and also mints 61 new millionaires.

**[Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2021/06/02/kinda-a-big-announcement/)**

> Today we’re pleased to announce that Stack Overflow is joining Prosus. Prosus is an investment and holding company, which means that the most important part of this announcement is that Stack Overflow will continue to operate independently, with the exact same team in place that has been operating it, according to the exact same plan and the exact same business practices. Don’t expect to see major changes or awkward “synergies”. The business of Stack Overflow will continue to focus on Reach and Relevance, and Stack Overflow for Teams. The entire company is staying in place: we just have different owners now.

> This is, in some ways, the best possible outcome. Stack Overflow stays independent. The company has plenty of cash on hand to expand and deliver more features and fix the old broken ones. Right now, the biggest gating factor to how fast we can do this is just how fast we can hire excellent people.

And **[the CEO of SO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/)**

> How you use our site and our products will not change in the coming weeks or months, just as our company’s goals and strategic priorities remain the same. As the acquisition is finalized, and we continue to partner with Prosus, I will keep you all posted through my regular quarterly blog posts and Teresa Dietrich, our Chief Product and Technology Officer, will do the same in her quarterly community blog posts.

Lest you think I'm just shooting from the hip here, [they're looking for a VP of community management](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here/3131115/vice-president-of-community-management). That was announced weeks ago. If you're not in good shape, and selling from a point of weakness, you don't put out stuff like that.

Yes, it would be easier with [some people still here to partake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342031/thank-you-shog9) and tell us it will be fine. But I don't think this bodes poorly for the community. Only time can truly tell, though...

Comment: This is all still very new and it will likely be months before we see any major impacts but from everything I'm hearing - this is a good thing. Prosus has an interest in building community - which is great, since that's something that makes our sites thrive and so making the public sites a place for people to work together more easily and ensure excellent content - that's what we all want, right? :)

Comment: It's been pretty obvious that they've tried to sell for several years now. Particularly shortly after the "firing moderators" debacle when they started to fire staff left & right, cutting down costs.

Comment: They always say it's "exciting changes" and it always means "changes that affect the users in a negative way"

Comment: "61 new millionaires" Yeah, that's what the world needs.

Comment: @miken32 ...and if you had worked hard at SO for years, helping to turn it into the product it is today and was one of those newly minted millionaires, how would you respond to someone that made your comment?

Comment: Why, my monocle might just pop right out into my caviar dish!

Comment: @JeffC The premise that Stack Overflow's staff have worked hard, at anything, is laughable. If they had, the features that we've been requesting for years would've been implemented.

Comment: Per Joel's comment "plenty of cash on hand to expand and deliver more features and fix the old broken ones",  I'm kinda looking forward to Wasabi 2.0 !

Comment: I've removed the sub-discussion about wealth and who should get it. If you want to discuss economic theories, there are some Stacks better suited.

Comment: Why did SO get sold for only $1.8b if Slack was sold for $27b? isn't SO way more valuable?

Comment: "scaling communities in high-growth markets globally, Prosus can help accelerate Stack Overflow’s growth" seems to indicate that there would be a push to increase net revenue, regardless of what the current format is or is not in the process. That the people who benefit most from this sale are adamant everything is going to remain the same is rather irrelevant to the fact that the purchase changes SO into a product to be commoditized instead of a knowledge base to be expanded; perhaps both can coexist, but that is not a guarantee.

Comment: @miken32 I don't think the world needs jealous, bitter commenters either. I can't imagine if you had the nous to create a successful business, you would refuse the cash. But there's the rub, people who _can't_ love to snipe at thoise who _do_. SE/SO has made the lives of innumerable people better, I;m glad some people are getting rich from that. Good for them.

Answer (score 37):

[Teresa Dietrich](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12719657/teresa-dietrich) (Our Chief Product Officer) answered this [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/365056/), since it's a pretty similar question I'll quote her directly:

> The TL;DR is not much this year. We have our current strategy, roadmaps and plans for this year and continue to be focused on those. It’s business as usual, as it says in our blog post, we would be operating independently. The leadership team is staying, including me. Most of the company just found out about this today and many are in shock and excited about the future. Prosus is very community-focused and excited about what you all have built. As we start to plan for 2022, I think we will see more opportunities to invest in our public platform sites and community. I will be publishing my State of the Stack blog and meta post this month and will go into more detail there.
>
> For now, if you want to know more, we have a bit more detail [on our blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/).

Comment: So maybe more programmers, more community manager and more implemented feature requests, but it's not clear and also could remain the same or something else. A selling is surely not business as usual though.

Answer (score 17):

[Officially, **for the time being**, nothing.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/06/02/prosus-acquires-stack-overflow/)

> How you use our site and our products will not change in the coming weeks or months, just as our company’s goals and strategic priorities remain the same. As the acquisition is finalized, and we continue to partner with Prosus, [[Prashanth](https://stackoverflow.com/company/leadership/prashanth-chandrasekar)] will keep you all posted through [his] regular quarterly blog posts and Teresa Dietrich, our Chief Product and Technology Officer, will do the same in her quarterly community blog posts.

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2021/06/02/kinda-a-big-announcement/ also seems to confirm not much change for now: "the most important part of this announcement is that Stack Overflow will continue to operate independently, with the exact same team in place that has been operating it, according to the exact same plan and the exact same business practices. Don’t expect to see major changes or awkward “synergies”. The business of Stack Overflow will continue to focus on Reach and Relevance, and Stack Overflow for Teams. The entire company is staying in place: we just have different owners now"

Comment: The qualifier is that nothing **for now** will change.  I can't forecast the future so I'm going to just rely on the moment here @Tinkeringbell.

Comment: I give it a week, two weeks tops, for this to change

Comment: @Zoe a missed 6 to 8 opportunity ....

Comment: @rene ah, but weeks is too optimistic, and days is too small a scope :p

Comment: so, keep on destroying the community to funnel paid products, business as usual

Comment: @KevinB: Anything not officially stated by the company in explicit and unambiguous language is all otherwise rumors and innuendo.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell: But big changes often happen about 2 years in, either disastrous (euphemism "restructuring") or much-needed innovation (like expanding into the learning part).

Comment: Let me put it this way: they paid a handsome amount of money for the right to claim that they own the Stack Overflow brand. That was not charity, there is going to have to be a return on investment. I can't really believe that with the way the site is now that amount of money is going to be made back and turned into profit in a timeframe that investors are comfortable with. That does not imply that StackOverflow.com is going to change, but I am pretty darned sure that different very commercial things are going to be launched under the brand name. Which is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: I compare it to Minecraft; Microsoft paid an exorbitant amount of money not for Minecraft: Java Edition but for "Minecraft" - the brand name that the entire world knows, and made sure to expand on the amount of products that can be bought related to that brand. But Minecraft: Java Edition is still there, going strong.

Comment: @Gimby But Minecraft is something one can buy. How do I buy a StackOverflow? Can I maybe buy visitors to my questions or reputation, a question ban breaker maybe? It seems much less straightforward to make money out of SO than out of Minecraft. SO, the company, tried that for years. I understand the value of the brand though. If I talk with others they call SO only the site who has all the answers and where everyone goes to.

Comment: @Gimby:  If I recall that story correctly, Microsoft acquired the company [Mojang and also Minecraft](https://news.xbox.com/en-us/2014/09/15/games-minecraft-to-join-microsoft/).  Microsoft didn't *just* take the brand with it, they brought the company with it and invested in it so that it could continue to grow.  All of its myriad editions (yes, even Java edition) are supported and maintained and updated by Mojang.

Comment: @Gimby:  Unlike Stack Overflow, which has made its business on the work of free or volunteer labor, Minecraft is something that people can buy and have an immediate investment in.  We have literal essays and mountains of prose written about "the best way to ask a question" and trying to dissect those is no small feat for the average passer-by.  The products that Stack Overflow wants to sell us are its enterprise Stack Overflow edition and the hiring portal, which...okay, they *might* work, but there's already a crowded space for those.

Comment: Maybe this is an affirmation that commercial things will be launched soon, but it's probably best for us to not kid ourselves about what had made the site so profitable.

Comment: @Makoto "it's probably best for us to not kid ourselves about what had made the site so profitable." The countless hours of unpaid labor of experts in their field, I guess. But is the site really that profitable? My impression was always that volunteers here rely on the site to remain essentially free to access. Doing work for free that results in a product that is available for free can probably be justified. But who would do free work for a purely commercial product? That might limit the profitability.

Comment: That's the beauty of it @Trilarion.  The products with actual price tags are their hiring portal and Stack Overflow Teams, *not* the main site.  The main site is really what gets people to the front door and what gets people to talk about the site as a whole.  The reputation of Stack Overflow allows it to carry on through other product chains and other product ventures, which is what brings the revenue in.  So it's *technically* not us professionals that are directly turning them a profit, but without us professionals, those products would never have been possible.

Comment: @Trilarion:  Anyone could copy the questions of Stack Overflow and republish them so long as they abide by CC-by-SA.  There's dozens of copycat sites that do that today.  But that's not where the profitability in the site lies.  It's the fact that people come to Stack Overflow at all to do their technical Q&A which makes it the household name and juggernaut it is today.

Comment: @Zoe Do investment companies typically change things that quickly? I've worked for two companies that got acquired and "not much this year" is spot on based on my experience but in my cases the acquiring companies were large businesses that already had their own products/services. As far as I can tell, Prosus just owns stuff. Maybe that matters?

Comment: @BSMP No clue, first time I've ever been on a site that got bought by an investment company. Still though, more money means more stuff that can be done, and that may have side-effects. /shrug

Comment: Considering the recent Microsoft-SSO auth madness going on with Minecraft, that's maybe not a great example

Comment: @forresthopkinsa In the minecraft community nobody cares about who owns them, whether it's microsoft or notch or mojang. So I think this worry about "things will change under prosus" is trash.

Comment: @forresthopkinsa funny enough, I wasn't able to play Minecraft for a long time due to some kind of login problem (I have a really old Mojang account that wasn't recognized for several months). It works now, though.

Comment: @jrh offtopic but you may have an old Minecraft **(NOT MOJANG)** account https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360034636772-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Account-Types

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 you're probably right. In the Minecraft client it's listed as a Mojang account. I'm not completely sure when I bought it, but I think it was in 2011, Beta 1.3 I think? I don't log in with an email, I log in with a username. I play the game so infrequently I might miss the window (oops).

Comment: Yeah, if you login with a username you should migrate your account. They're deprecated and probably will be removed once Microsoft accounts are finalised. http://account.mojang.com/migrate

Comment: @TheTechRobo36414519 Checking in about 6 months later, so much for "early 2021", looks like that migration did not happen.

Comment: Nah, they're doing it. However, people like me don't like it and so hold off.

Answer (score 15):

*Note: This post is being updated to show the actual changes associated with the roadmap I described in 2021.*

---

**Forward looking statement**

Overall, I think what we will see in the near term is no significant changes, perhaps some minor investments (For example, [Collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408585/beta-release-of-collectives-on-stack-overflow)); in the mid term, an alteration to the way that advertising is served (For example [The Future of our Jobs Ad slots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416964/1026459), ["Reach and Relevance"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/07/an-update-on-our-product-led-saas-transformation/?_ga=2.228814300.1143219700.1643051169-1434905743.1550786406), and [Privacy Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/370343/178816)) and some phasing out of underperforming facets of the exchange (For example, [Jobs and Dev Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story#comment891198_415293)); in the long term a purchase by another firm as profitability here wanes (For example, the [Layoffs on May 10 2023](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389060/2023-layoff-impacting-58-so-se-staff-2023-05-10) and the [Layoffs on October 16 2023](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393791/community-notice-october-2023-layoff-announcement)), probably a large tech company who would put this to good use somewhere.

Don't worry too much though, this place makes enough money and has a large enough community to survive the process. Just focus on creating good content that stands the test of time. Maybe even have some fun and help someone along the way.

**State of SO at the time of sale**

What happens to Stack Overflow is no longer up to anyone here; not the CEO, the board, no one, has a say in the future of the business of Stack Overflow.

What happens is purely up to the outlook of whomever decided to purchase the platform. Seeing as how they spent $1.8B it means that there is a serious investment in the success of the site and overall product, so that is good. However, what that also means is that this is now going to be purely governed by monetary milestones from either an oversight board or an investment group.

Everyone cited - Atwood, Spolsky, Prashanth - they all strongly mention money as what is changing. Money always comes with strings attached when it is influenced by such a large group. There will now more than likely be consequences for parts of the exchange failing to perform financially.

Let's all be clear though, Prosus didn't purchase Stack Overflow... Naspers did. The CEO and board are who make large purchases like this, and Naspers (who fully owns Prosus) is the CEO and board for Prosus. Bob van Dijk is the current CEO of both Naspers and Prosus. Naspers was founded as a publication company, with the mission statement "for the free unimpeded expression of public opinion on all major issues".  So, while having someone like Bob there who has experience from eBay and Allegro, and a general outlook of having free expression, it would seem a good fit. One would hope this place was left in good hands.

On the other hand, Naspers is so big that it has its hands in both good and bad places. While the "corporate learning companies" segment seems good, there are also a wide variety of other internet segments which may have a conflict of interest with regards to the way we see advertising.

Comment: "Just focus on creating good content..." I wish it would be possible. The number or newly registered users and questions went up since the beginning of 2020, but the ratio of answers to question is barely 1:1 now and long time users are never to be seen again. Going through the new questions on the homepage mostly bad content is served. I don't want to waste my time searching for something answerable there. The only valuable activity to me left is improving existing content by editing. That's still fun. If anything I will work on building a non-profit alternative with all the valuable content.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way. From my perspective, over enforcement is what has dropped the answer to question ratio, as questions which would generally have more than 1 answer are now discouraged through interpretation. The semantic focus is ridiculously skewed in the wrong direction, and as a result, questions which users enjoy are no longer as common. If everyone in tech had to suddenly stop asking people "here is a my situation, how would you approach that?" then nothing would get done, which is exactly what has happened here. If anything, zeal is to blame for this more than new users or Prosus

Comment: There is surely something to it, I agree. Many questions could be salvaged with a bit of patience while the initial impulse rather seems to be to close as much as possible. On the other hand I see like 95% (my estimation) of new questions without any research and so many of them are trivial but not very interesting to answer. I blame the laziness of people for the high amount of low quality questions but I'm not sure who to blame for the absence of high quality questions. Often enough I find answers to the problems I encounter already and don't need to ask at all.

Comment: Just a small comment on a possible evolution of Q&A either by StackOverflow/Naspers or by anyone else: I would like to see better matchmaking between those with questions and those with answers. I know which kind of questions I'd like to answer but I don't want to spend much time on finding those first. I guess that a good chunk of Q&A done right would deal with bringing the right kind of people together and that there is still room for improvement. I basically don't mind if others have different criteria for what is worth their time, the system could just would work better for everyone.