# The Future of our Jobs Ad slots

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising, announcement

Over the course of the next few weeks, you may see some changes to the content in the right-sidebar on Stack Overflow, and I am here to let you know what to expect.

For background, as you probably know, [we recently announced that we are shutting down our Jobs and Developer Story features](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story). While some found job-related products useful, we learned that most job seekers don’t actually turn to job boards as a primary resource. We determined that discontinuing job-related products would help us better serve developers and the broader community long-term. One consequence of this is that we will need to make changes to the dedicated ad unit for Jobs. We've always carried this ad placement, presented in the lower of the two right-hand sidebar ads on Stack Overflow, and used it to promote a list of relevant job opportunities.

**Beginning April 4th, you may see that we’re showing traditional display ads in the space formerly reserved for Jobs ads. This is a temporary move while we're working on new features related to online learning and skill-building for our core community. Once we're ready to roll these out, we will replace the traditional display ads in that placement with content related to learning and development.** We're in the early stages of discovery and will have more to share with you about this soon.

I’ve written up some basic FAQs for this changeover, and if you have other questions related to this change, please feel free to leave them here, and we’ll be back to attempt to answer them.

## FAQ

1. **What’s going on?  It feels like the site has more ads than ever.**

   For several years, we have used the second ad slot on the right side of the page to promote relevant jobs from our Talent line-of-business. Since we’re retiring that portion of the business, that leaves an ad slot open and ready for use. Our plan is to explore using that ad slot for specialized ads related to skill-building and online learning. As we build out the tech necessary to support this, we’re temporarily running traditional display ads there. Once we’re ready to proceed with the new ad type, we’ll carefully phase out the display ads and replace them with the new ads.
2. **Which ad placement is involved?**

   It’s the second (lower) sidebar ad on the right hand side of the page, and only on Stack Overflow.
3. **Why is this being done?**

   When we retired the jobs portion of the business, we were left with some significant holes in the ad space calendar. We are currently testing using those slots as normal display advertisements.  The primary “customer” for those ads was our own jobs network.
4. **How can I opt out of seeing ads on the site?**

   Community members who are logged in with at least 200 reputation can [choose to turn off some advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) (the top and bottom “leaderboard” ads) by going to your profile, then hitting “settings” in the upper left hand corner, then scrolling down to the end of the page and turning off the “Enable advertisements” option.

Comment: Please edit the question to tell us why it is not possible to remove it entirely ;)

Comment: "we learned that most job seekers don’t actually turn to job boards as a primary resource" -- would love to know what they (we) use instead

Comment: @lofidevops I've always heard that networking is how most people find their jobs, but that's not my experience. Personally, of the 5 offers I have received in the past few years, 2 were from university-organized events, 2 were from my applications on job boards, and 1 was from an inhouse recruiter contacting me on a job board.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at the jobs board here for several years to learn of interesting places with openings (especially in C++) - Craiglist _used_ to be a great place to explore for hardcore software engineering jobs (in the Seattle area) but hasn't been for ... well, quite a long time now.  Years.  I'm not a LinkedIn user but I bet that's where a lot of people look these days.  (But would like to hear more.)

Comment: "4. How can I opt out of seeing ads on the site?" just run an ad blocker. The site works fine when running one.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat It's been my experience. I've had something like 15 jobs, of which 2 I found through job boards, and all the rest were networking (mostly, people I met while doing one job approached me as my contract came to an end).

Comment: "*will replace the [old ads] with content related to learning and development.*" - sounds like business speak. I think the phrase "*replace them with the new ads*" in your FAQ is much more honest.

Comment: Thanks for letting us opt out of these, that's definitely an improvement! Could you please update the [help text on "reduced ads"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)? It still says "*sidebar ads will remain visible*".

Comment: @lofidevops I mean, if you're good, you'll probably do a direct apply, right? I have to imagine that companies that can attract direct applies receive the best candidates. Which is why I'm lamenting the loss of job boards some: Smaller companies need the exposure, the ability to list attractive job descriptions. Of course, [the SO jobs board had already cut out little companies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410885/1028230). I was hoping they'd move the jobs board towards self-service, but instead they kilt it.

Comment: @lofidevops Maybe thats something they could put on the developer survey. Something like, 'what did you use to find your current job'?

Comment: SO jobs was wonderful. Please bring it back!!!

Comment: What else am I supposed to do with all my rep??? They killed the one useful feature beyond the core site

Comment: So, I decode this as *"We intend to replace job ads with a direct lead funnel to online learning sites as we think that will monetize better. In the meantime, please enjoy these ads"*

Comment: I also lament this change.

Comment: I hate when a business lies to you to try to make you think what they're doing is for you, not for them. It's perfectly understandable if the business wants to make more money, but don't try to phrase it like "You hated this job board, so we got rid of it!"

Comment: Kill the job board, but keep the CV functionality! Being able to have an interactive CV like we had was king.

Comment: Reinstate Jobs! I support Jobs! I stand with Jobs!

Comment: _"This is a temporary move while we're working on new features related to online learning and skill-building for our core community."_ I guess we will see a lot of Udemy  or Codecademy ads/linked features in the future. Well played Prosus.

Comment: When I downvoted it said that I should make a comment if this could be improved, so this is how this can be improved: Dont delete jobs and dev story

Answer (score 118):

I must say I'm somewhat disappointed by this change. Even though I haven't been searching for a job for awhile, I still found it helpful to see what people were hiring for to make sure that I'm staying current with my skills.

It would be nice if these ads filled a similar function somehow, as I would like to continue to have a feature that lets me track that easily.

Comment: Am i the only one who doesn't get any ads on this site? Even with my adblocker off I only get one ad and it is usually an SOs ad

Comment: @S.Dre Do you geolocate to the USA? Some display ads may not be offered/monetize for some international users. This is not specific to SO.

Comment: Nope, not in the US

Answer (score 85):

> While some found job-related products useful...

"Some" is really an understatement. The announcement of retiring job and Developer Story is the most downvoted question in the history of StackOverflow: https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1575199/most-down-voted-questions

> ...we learned that most job seekers don’t actually turn to job boards as a primary resource...

What is the source? Analytics from Stack Overflow is not enough. Such statement needs to be comparative with other big domains.

Now, are the job/learning platform ads going to be curated by Stack Overflow? If so, how come is this different than maintaining the old job posting?

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: there will not be job ads and this announcement in no implies there will be. We're replacing the slot that used to be reserved for jobs with other things.

Comment: @animuson "Our plan is to explore using that ad slot for specialized ads related to skill-building and online learning" -> still needs to be curated. Online learning is full of platforms that exploit human necessity offering high rewards that are not meet in the long run.

Comment: Ok... But what does that have to do with expecting job ads or comparing it to the previous Jobs platform?

Comment: @animuson I'm not sure I follow. What does asking about ad curation have to do with "expecting job ads". I believe the intent of the question was to highlight that either there will be curation to weed out the cruff that  litters the "online learning space" thus little labor savings for SO, or there would be no curation and SO users would be shown the predator cruff.

Comment: @JonSG The original version of this answer only mentioned job ads in the last paragraph, as if we were finding a new way to advertise jobs. We've always had regular ads that are subjected to tight standards, and this would just be dedicating an ad slot to a subset of that, similar to how we dedicate some space to [community ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/community-ads).

Comment: @animuson Many thanks for the clarification

Comment: It is interesting to see how people hated developer story when it was introduced and also hated it when it was discontinued.

Comment: I didn't care much for Developer Story, either when it was introduced or when it was discontinued. But I think the loss of the traditional CV view was a big mistake, and for the people who liked Developer Story, I can see why that is also a big mistake. I don't understand why the team didn't just roll that into the existing personal profile page, as additional tabs, even if they wanted to discontinue the Jobs site proper as a place to list and apply for Jobs. (Although I also lament the end of the Jobs site, as I agreed with its mission in a field of so much crap and parasitism.) @totymedli

Comment: @CodyGray Absolutely agree. I loved the fact that I had a clean, easy to update CV linked to my SO account and I hate to see it go too. Same for the Jobs site (although the CV thingy is more important for me) it was the best jobs listing site that I knew. Way better than LinkedIn.

Comment: I think the source of this is the accounting department of SO.

Comment: Some of the now-deleted posts regarding Monica's firing may have been more downvoted.

Comment: @CodyGray ^ ^ ^ Absolutely agree as well!

Answer (score 34):

People may not like traditional job boards (though I strongly disagree that they don't use them as a primary search) but they always seemed to love *good* job boards that attracted well set up companies. Back in the days of the Joel Test for example.

"we've got some space, let's stick ads in it" doesn't seem a decision made to benefit the community.

Answer (score 9):

Just as @EJoshuaS says: If I would be looking for a job, I certainly would take a peek into the job ads.
I read the job ads also (without clicking though), just to slightly keeping up with the job market, and for economic signals as well. And last but not least, job ads are actually the only one making sense to click on, as for the mutual interest part of finding eachother.

But ofcourse that potential doesn't count for the analytics, as it's not a measureable fact.
Therefore, I would love to vote for keeping the job ads, if that is an option.
But that's probably no option anyway...

I do see the value added of paid private Teams, though I'm not subscribed. And I do love StackExchange for its open communities. It's like a public library, where you can pay for extra services, which should "keep the shop open".
I just never heard of a commercial library. Why every visitor must be monetized by adding sales ads?